# Height and distance with directions

Tags: trigonometry

From a point due south of a tower, a man observes the angle of elevation of the top of the tower to be 60°. He then walks 60m due west on the horizontal plane and observes the angle of elevation to be 30°. Find the height of the tower and his initial distance from the tower..

My attempt

[image]

I have the figure but I could not solve it to get the answer.  please anyone solve this figure.

solving the figure, the initial distance.from the tower to the man does not match. The initial distance between the tower and the man is 63.63m. Where is the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the figure below.

[image: height_of_tower]

The man is initially at point $S$, standing a distance $d$ from the base $B$ of the tower, which has height $h$.  He measures the angle of elevation, $\angle BST$, to be $60^\circ$.  He then moves $60~\text{m}$ west from $S$ to point $W$, where he measures the angle of elevation, $\angle BWT$, to be $30^\circ$.

Then 
\begin{align*}
\tan 60^\circ & = \frac{h}{d}\\
\sqrt{3} & = \frac{h}{d}\\
d\sqrt{3} & = h
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\tan 30^\circ & = \frac{h}{x}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & = \frac{h}{x}\\
x & = h\sqrt{3}\\
  & = (d\sqrt{3})\sqrt{3}\\
  & = 3d
\end{align*} 
Moreover, since $S$ is directly south of the tower and $W$ is directly west of $S$, $\angle BSW$ is a right angle, so $\triangle BSW$ is a right triangle with hypotenuse $\overline{BW}$.  Hence, by the Pythagorean Theorem,
$$d^2 + (60~\text{m})^2 = (3d)^2$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Taussig, what is his initial distance from the tower?

Comment: Edited.  His initial distance from the tower is $d$.

Comment: But the answer doesn't match. The answer in my book is 63.63m.

Comment: The number in the book appears to be his distance from the tower when he takes the second reading, which is $x$ in my drawing.  I suggest you edit your question to state the book's answers for his initial distance and the height of the tower.  That could attract renewed attention to your question, which could reveal an error in the answers you have already received (which agree) or in the text you are using.

Comment: What answer, if any, does the book give for the height of the tower?

Comment: The answer for the height of the tower is 36.74m

Comment: The answers I obtain for the initial distance of the man from the tower, the height of the tower, and his distance from the tower when he takes the second measurement are, respectively, $d = \sqrt{450}~\text{m} \approx 21.21~\text{m}$, $h = \sqrt{1350}~\text{m} \approx 36.74~\text{m}$, and $x = 3d  \approx 63.64~\text{m}$.  The book's answers are inconsistent.  Since the angle of elevation is initially $60^\circ$, the height of the tower must exceed the man's initial distance from the tower.

Comment: Then which answers are correct?

Comment: I believe that my answer and those given by infinitely curious are correct, that the book's answer for the height of the tower is correct, and that the book's answer for the man's initial answer is incorrect.  Instead, the answer of $63.63~\text{m}$ the author(s) gave you is the distance from the position where the man measured the angle of elevation to be $30^\circ$ to the base of the tower.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the figure below.

[image: height_of_tower]

Since the figure for this question will be formed in 3D and I have to adjust it in 2D I will have to represent the $90^\circ$ like that.

$$\tan 60^\circ =AB/BC$$
$$therefore~BC=AB/{\sqrt3 } \tag{1}$$
$$\tan 30^\circ =AB/DB$$
$$therefore~DB=\sqrt{3}AB \tag{2}$$
$${BC^2}+{DC^2}={DB^2}$$
$${AB^2}/{3}+3600=3{AB^2} (as\hspace{1 mm} DC=60m)$$
$$therefore\hspace{1 mm} AB=\sqrt {1350}=36.742m$$
$$BC=AB/{\sqrt3}~(eqn. 1)$$
$$therefore\hspace{1 mm} BC=21.21m$$
$$AB=height\hspace{1 mm} of\hspace{1 mm} tower=36.742m$$
$$BC = initial \hspace{1 mm}distance\hspace{1 mm} from \hspace{1 mm}tower = 21.21m$$

Comment: what is his initial distance from the tower, then?

Comment: BC I.e 21.21 metres